# ¿Cómo puedo acelerar el renderizado de mí aplicación?

Tags: c#

lo que pasa es que tengo una aplicación de Windows Forms la cual tiene muchos controles e imágenes, y, para empeorar la situación, checa una variable y con esa, determina si el tema de la aplicación es blanco o negro, es decir, hice un if el cual verifica si un bool es verdadero o falso, y con ese valor, determina si debe cambiar el color a blanco o a negro.
Aparte ésta crea muchos User control por código, así que tarda aproximadamente unos 5-8 segundos en renderizar todo, entonces, quería saber cómo podría cargar la Interfaz de la ventana sin mostrarla, para que cuando se termine de cargar, solo aparezca la ventana y ya no se tenga que ver mientras se carga, ya he intentando con el método this.SuspendLayout pero no funciona.

Comment: te refieres al abrir la aplicacion o al compilar tu proyecto?

Comment: Al abrir una ventana

Comment: normalmente se crea un modal de cargando mientras se cargan los componentes en memoria y cuando finaliza de cargar, se cierra el modal y se muestra la pantalla

Comment: Hola. Has probado a usar esto en el Load de tu formulario? "SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer);"

Comment: @SergioParraGuerra  ¿Qué es lo que hace exactamente?

Comment: Aplicar DoubleBuffering en el renderizado

Comment: @SergioParraGuerra  Y ese código se aplica en el designer o en el código del formulario?

Comment: Te propongo leas esta documentación, [Cómo: Reducir el parpadeo de los gráficos con un búfer doble en formularios y controles](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-reduce-graphics-flicker-with-double-buffering-for-forms-and-controls)

Comment: El designer es código de formulario. Fíjate en que es una clase parcial de tu Form

Comment: Tambien puedes intentar cargar la ventana sin mostrarla (Hide) luego hacer Show